# Failing an audit for an answer after reviewing the questions top answer

Tags: support, feature-request, disputed-review-audits

I just failed an audit from an "unknown user" in the first post review queue.

The audited post was an answer.

I looked at the question and it's answers, to see if anyone else gave better answers already and if the answer given by the review candidate adds anything. (Especially because it was so short and seemed wrong to me, not answering the question directly)

After inspection I found that the answer was a blatant copy and paste from the top answer which was accepted aswell.

I downvoted and was about to report the answer.

"This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.

Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above."

So I failed by paying to much attention ?

Hiding the username in this case puts reviewers looking too deep into stuff off. I recommend recycling the username and faking the reputation to be 1 or suggesting that the post was made by a guest account with the same name by faking the link on the username. This would avoid misunderstandings, while detecting zombievoters or people doing the wrong stuff. At the same time it avoids the conclusion that the poster was plagiarising or is a bot.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14344529

Comment: The last section of [this FAQ](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506/4099598) is highly relevant. It's unfortunate that you can fail an audit for paying more attention than normal if you don't pay *enough* attention, but take heart that, in future, it *is* possible and even fairly straightforward (once you know the trick) to avoid such problems.

Comment: You wrote, "I found that the answer was a blatant copy and paste from the top answer which was accepted aswell." What do you mean? The answer that is the subject of the audit *is* the top and accepted answer.

Comment: I think the audit system is not fully correct.

Comment: @EdCottrell The user was obfuscated, so I thought another user copy and pasted the top answer.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Still, only one user posted that answer...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're new to reviewing.

Taking the link to the post will *always* reveal if it's an audit task. You need to know how to spot it. Here are the things that audits typically do:

- Score reset to 0
- Usercard made anonymous
- Checkmark removed

If you spot those distortions, review No Action Needed, edit it, or upvote it. Really, if you're paying attention this much, you're doing *amazing*.

I don't think that changing the usercard on audits would do much. The audit system is doing fine as-is. In fact, an even better proposal would be to just drop the usercard in review altogether; nobody should need to review a post based on the poster.